# Is the function $y= e^ {x^2} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt$ is a solution of the differential equation $y'= 2xy + 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is the  function  $y= e^ {x^2} \int_{0}^{x}  e^{-t^2} dt$ is  a  solution  of the differential equation  $y'= 2xy + 1$

My attempt : I don't think so  , because  $\int y' =  2y \frac{x^2}{2} + x + C=y\tag 1$

from $(1)$  we can   said that  $2y \frac{x^2}{2} + x + C \neq y$

So $y= e^ {x^2} \int_{0}^{x}  e^{-t^2} dt$ is  not a   solution  of the differential equation  $y'= 2xy + 1$

Comment: You can't just compute the integral of $y'$ directly as $y = y(x)$ so $$\int y' dx = \int 2xy + 1 dx \ne 2y \frac{x^{2}}{2}$$ Just differentiate $$y' = 2x e^{x^{2}} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^{2}} dt + e^{x^{2}} \cdot e^{-x^{2}} = \dots$$

Comment: ohh @mattos okss

Comment: In fact it's the solution of the DE for the constant $c=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say $\int (2xy+1)dx=2y\frac{x^2}2+x+C$ you are ignoring the fact that $y$ depends on $x$, so this is not correct.

A better approach is to differentiate the proposed $y$ and see if it satisfies the equation
$$y= e^ {x^2} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt\\y'=2xe^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt+e^{x^2}e^{-x^2}=2xy+1$$
Where we used the product rule to get the two terms and the fundamental theorem of calculus to get the derivative of the integral with respect to the upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate $y'$ directly and check whether the equation holds. We'll first calculate the derivative of each term in the product,
$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{x^2} = 2x e^{x^2}, \qquad \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \; dt = e^{-x^2}$$
and now use the product rule to obtain
\begin{align*}
y' &= \left(2xe^{x^2}\right) \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \; dt + e^{x^2} \cdot e^{-x^2} \\
&= 2x \left(e^{x^2} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \; dt \right) + 1 \\
&= 2xy + 1
\end{align*}
where we've observed that the term in brackets on the penultimate line is $y$ - hence it is indeed a solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$y= e^ {x^2} \int_{0}^{x}  e^{-t^2} dt$$
By Leibniz rule:
$$y'=2xe^ {x^2} \int_{0}^{x}  e^{-t^2} dt+1=2xy+1$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also go ahead and solve the DE.
$$ y' = 2xy + 1 $$
$$ y'-2xy = 1 $$
now apply the integrating factor $e^{-x^2}$, thus
$$ (ye^{-x^2})' = e^{-x^2} $$
hence
$$ y= ce^{x^2} + e^{x^2} \int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt $$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constat (since there is no initial condition). Choosing $c=0$ gives that it is indeed a solution.